# Correct way to make ANCOVA in R for RCT

Tags: r, ancova

I know there is already some information on the subject but I find different variantes, do not quite understand the differences and their effects and want to make sure I do not make a mistake.
I have data a RCT with a measurement repetition and would like to analyze this correctly in R:
Is the analysis in wideformat a viable way?

```
fit <- lm(SCORE_total_t1~ group + SCORE_total_t0, data=data.wide)
summary(fit)
# or
res.aov <- anova_test(SCORE_total_t1 ~ group + SCORE_total_t0, data=data.wide)
get_anova_table(res.aov)
```

Thanks for everyone who takes the time to help me

Comment: What do you mean by 'measurement repetition'?  Do you have more than one response variable measurements per subject?

Comment: I have score at timepoint t0 and 6 month later with t1 while in these 6 months the case group got an intervention and the control group got care as usual

Comment: So you have one baseline measurement (pre-randomization) and one follow-up measurement?  That would make sense in your original formulation, i.e., you don't need a longitudinal analysis.

Comment: exactly t0 is randomization independent and the longitudinal analysis does not matter it is only about the effect of the intervention